# I'm looking for a word that means something bad could happen

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means something bad could happen. To use it in a sentence:
"Throughout my child hood the phrase “Life is about taking chances” was a common thing to say in my household, but what if those chances had really bad _____."
I used the word outcome for the blank but that does not fit the sentence.

Comment: There's not a way of just adding a word here. '... but what if taking those chances had resulted in really bad outcomes?' would work.

Comment: Maybe you could rewrite your sentence to read something like this: "Throughout my childhood, the phrase “Life is about taking chances” was bandied about my household, but that saying filled me with [foreboding."](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/foreboding) (That is, with a strong inner feeling or notion of a future misfortune, evil, etc.; presentiment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ***consequences***?

***Consequence*** could be a neutral word, but in the right timing, it gives an ominous air of something ill-boding approaching via cause and effect.

As it is, the word ***consequence*** has the meaning of the effect of a causation or event or action. It is used often in literature when the dramatic effect necessitates something more negative than an "outcome". In your sentence:

> "Throughout my child hood the phrase “Life is about taking chances”
>   was a common thing to say in my household, but what if those chances
>   had really bad ***consequences***?"

You might even step this up a notch by replacing "bad" with "terrible", "gruesome", "unlucky", "unfair", or whatever else strikes a mood.